# @RestController returning forms to the same page but with different URL

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spring-restcontroller

I'm using @RestController to manage some different forms prom a page (with Thymeleaf), and it works fine, but the URL in the browser is not 'reset' even I create a new ModelAndView every time:

Example:
Initial URL: `http://localhost:8090/project/v1/controller/`

URL after some action in RestContorller: `http://localhost:8090/project/v1/controller/actionA`

My desired URL: `http://localhost:8090/project/v1/controller/`

My Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("myObj", this.someMethods());
        mav.setViewName("index"); //my page
        return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, params = "action=actionA")
    public ModelAndView actionA(...) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("myObj", this.someMethods());
        mav.setViewName("index"); //again the same page
        return mav;
}
```

I can't use the same value parameter because this is used in my page in forms/actions to identify the method to be executed in restcontroller, example:

```
<form id="action" method="POST" th:object="${Object}"
              th:action="@{/v1/emulador-central/action}">
...
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="actionA" class="btn btn-primary">Aprovar</button>
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="actionB" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;">Reprovar</button>
...
</form>
```

I tried use redirect but without success, and I tried create a new method POST to create ModelAndView and then return this object to my index, another fail.
Can someone tell me how I can do it properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about mapping the POST also to value = "/" instead of value = "/actionA" ?

Comment: I can't do that, because this value is the parameter used inside a form in my page, to identify the method of my RestController I want to execute, so I need distinct value parameters

Comment: If someone have the same problem, until now I can't figure it out. When I find the solution I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

**@RestController** doesn't change the page or redirect another page generally.

Rest Controller dealing with rest api what is render json, plain text etc.

If you need to render or redirect html page why use **@RestController** ?

**Just use:**

```
      @Controller
```

Your problem solved.

Comment: I'm using that because the structure of the projects in the company, and as I said, it works fine and without trouble, just the URL in the browser. So, I don't think is that the trouble, but I'll try here, and give a feedback soon.